# Request body is not properly feined in loadtest

Tags: node.js, load-testing

I was using [loadtest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loadtest) for load tetsing of my node app. I had issue sending post requests via loadtest. The request is of the form:

```
loadtest http://localhost:7000/eth/checkEthBalance -T "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -m "POST" --data '{"accountAddress":"0x62720366ef403c9891e2bfbd5358ee3c8a57b113"}' -n 1
```

But in `req.body`, I am getting:

```
{ '{"accountAddress":"0x62720366ef403c9891e2bfbd5358ee3c8a57b113"}': '' }
```

instead of:

```
{"accountAddress":"0x62720366ef403c9891e2bfbd5358ee3c8a57b113"}
```

However a curl request workd fab:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:7000/eth/checkEthBalance \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'postman-token: 0bf637f7-2037-c4ca-29a7-cc2310786317' \
  -d accountAddress=0x62720366ef403c9891e2bfbd5358ee3c8a57b113
```

DOn't know what's wrong with loadtest. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Here how I did it, you need to pass `-T 'application/json'`

Sample : `loadtest -P '{"name" : "ashok dey", "email" : "ashokdey@gmail.com", "password" : "password123"}'  -c 100 --rps 2000 http://localhost:3434/register -T 'application/json'`

You have to pass the same when you are passing a file containing the post data.